# If $xR=I$ we can say that $x\in I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Probably this is a dumb question, I lack knowledge on abstract algebra. Suppose that $R$ is a ring without unity and $I\subset R$ is a non-trivial ideal.

If $xR=Rx=I$ for some $x\in R$, we can says that $x\in I$? If not, there is some other conditions that ensures that $x\in I$?

Comment: It is a reasonable question.  If you want to think about it, consider $R$ to be a proper ideal of a your favorite ring *with* unity.  Then $xR$ will be an ideal of $R$, and a suitable choice of $x$ will give you an answer.

Comment: Suppose $R=2\mathbb{Z}$, $I=4\mathbb{Z}$, and $x=2$.

Comment: @hardmath I hope their favorite ring is a nonfield domain! If they only like von Neumann regular rings they won't find a counterexample with that hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request for a counterexample has already been amply covered by existing answers/comments mentioning subrngs of $\mathbb Z$.

> If $xR=Rx=I$ for some $x\in R$, we can says that $x\in I$? If not, there is some other conditions that ensures that $x\in I$?

Trivially $R$ having identity ensures this, but I understand you're probably interested in weaker conditions.

One interesting condition that jumps to mind for me is for $I$ to be a [modular ideal](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Modular_ideal).  If $I$ is left modular, that means that there exists $e\in R$ such that $re-r\in I$ for all $r\in R$. (Said another way, $R/I$ has a right identity.)

But now look at what that would mean for $I=xR=Rx$:  you'd have $xe-x\in I$, but you already know $xe\in I$, so that would mean $x\in I$ as well.

Obviously being right modular would suffice as well, given your assumption that $Rx=I$.

Answer (score 2):

Per Michael Burr's suggestion in the comments, look at $R=2\mathbb Z$, $I=4\mathbb Z$, and $x=2$. $xR=Rx=4\mathbb Z=I$, but obviously, $2\notin4\mathbb Z$.