# Show that any non-trivial ideal of $(L_1,*)$ is dense

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, lp-spaces, convolution

This is related to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048119/if-xr-i-we-can-say-that-x-in-i/3048548#3048548), I mean, the linked question comes to my mind trying to solve the following exercise:

> Show that any non-trivial ideal of $(L_1,*)$ is dense.

Here $(L_1,*)$ is the space $L_1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ and $*$ stay for convolution. I know that $(L_1,+,*)$ is a Banach algebra without unity. I dont know the concept of "ideal" related to a Banach algebra so I assumed that it is asking for a set $I\subset L_1$ such that $f*\varphi\in I$ for any pair $(f,\varphi)\in L_1\times I$.

Correct me if my interpretation was wrong.

---

**FIRST APPROACH:** I know that if $g\in L_1$ and $\|g\|_1=1$ then $g_\epsilon(x):=\epsilon^{-n}g(x/\epsilon)$ defines a kernel $\{g_\epsilon:\epsilon>0\}$ that approximates the unity, that is, I know that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} g_\epsilon* f=\|g\|_1 f=f\tag1$$

in $L_1$ for any chosen $f\in L_1$.

Then my first idea was construct some approximation to the unity from a function $f*\varphi\in I$ (where $(f,\varphi)\in L_1\times I$), that is, I want to show that if $f*\varphi\in I$ then $(f*\varphi)_\epsilon\in I$ for any $\epsilon>0$, from here it would be easy to see that

$$h_\epsilon:=\frac{(f*\varphi)_\epsilon}{\|f*\varphi\|_1}\in I\tag2$$

and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}h_\epsilon*r=r$ for any chosen $r\in L_1$, what would imply that $I$ is dense in $L_1$. Then note that

$$(f*\varphi)_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\int f(x/\epsilon-y)\varphi(y)\, dy=\epsilon^{-n}\int f(x-y+K)\varphi(y)\, dy\tag3$$

for $K:= x/\epsilon-x$. Then also note that $\epsilon^{-n} f(\,\cdot+K)\in L_1$ for any chosen $K\in\Bbb R^n$, so an heuristic argument make me think from $(3)$ that $(f*\varphi)_\epsilon\in I$. However, this heuristic argument seems wrong, because we cannot fix $K$ as a constant and say that $g(x-y):=f(x/\epsilon-y)$ belongs to $L_1$ because $g$ is not well-defined.

---

**SECOND APPROACH:**

Note that

$$(f*\varphi)_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\int f(x/\epsilon-y)\varphi(y)\, dy=\epsilon^{-n}\int \tau_{x/\epsilon}\check f(y)\varphi(y)\, dy\\
=\epsilon^{-n}\int(\tau_{x/\epsilon}\check f\cdot \varphi)(y)\, dy
=\epsilon^{-2n}\int\tau_{x/\epsilon}\check f(y/\epsilon)\varphi(y/\epsilon)\, dy
\\=\epsilon^{-2n}\int f\left(\frac{x-y}\epsilon\right)\varphi(y/\epsilon)=(f_\epsilon*\varphi_\epsilon)(x)\tag4$$

where $\tau_a f(x)=f(x+a)$ and $\check f(x)= f(-x)$. Then it would be enough to show that if $\varphi\in I$ then $\varphi_\epsilon\in I$, but this doesn't seems feasible.

---

**THIRD APPROACH:**

Let any smoothing kernel $\{\varphi_\epsilon:\epsilon>0\}\subset L_1$ (by example the Gaussian kernel) and some $\psi\in I\setminus\{0\}$. Then, by the definition of ideal, we knows that $\varphi_\epsilon*\psi\in I$ for all $\epsilon>0$, thus by $(1)$ we can see that $\psi$ is a limit point of $I$, and because this holds for every function on the ideal then we conclude that $I$ is closed and perfect.

Then, if $I$ is dense, it must be the case that $I=L_1$. However Im again stuck here, that is, I dont know how to show that $I=L_1$.

Moreover: if it would be true that $I=L_1$ then $I$ is, indeed, a trivial ideal of $L_1$, contradicting the existence of non-trivial ideals, so the statement to be proved will be a vacuous truth.

---

Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: An ideal in an algebra should also be a linear subspace, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ideal.html, last paragraph.  So $I$ is also closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: In Approach #3, showing that every point of $I$ is a limit point of $I$ would imply that $I$ is perfect, but would not imply that it is closed.

Comment: It seems false to me, please tell me if you spot mistakes. Take a Schwartz function $\psi$ such that its Fourier transform $\hat\psi=\mathcal{F}(\psi)$ vanishes in some open set. Then $I:=\{f*\psi:f\in L^1\}$ is an ideal, but each of its elements has a Fourier transform that vanishes in the same open set, because $\widehat{f*\psi}=\hat f\hat\psi$. If $I$ were dense, by the continuity of $\mathcal{F}:L^1\to L^\infty$, $\mathcal{F}(I)$ would be dense in $\mathcal{F}(L^1)$ with $L^\infty$ norm. But this is not true: consider a function whose Fourier transform does not vanish where $\hat\psi$ does